# Emberjs transition to route causes "Cannot read property" error

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a strange error that I can't figure out. My app has a dashboard with nested routes. When I try to navigate away from the dashboard to any other routes I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'NotificationRead' of undefined`. NotificationRead is a property in my template. If I try to navigate from say the homepage to the settings page, I don't get an error. It's only when I try moving from the dashboard to any other page.

Here are my routes.

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    // Dashboard
    this.resource('vehicle', {
        path: '/dashboard'
    }, function() {
        this.resource('alerts', {
            path: 'notifications'
        }, function() {
            this.resource('alert', {
                path: ':alert_id'
            });
        });
        this.resource('reminders', {
            path: 'reminders'
        }, function() {
            this.resource('reminder', {
                path: ':reminder_id'
            });
        });
    });

    // this.resource('alerts', {
    //     path: 'alerts'
    // });

    this.route('settings', {
        path: '/settings'
    });

    this.resource('support', {
        path: '/support'
    });
});
```

All my links are rendered using `{{link-to}}{{/link-to}}`. The property that is Ember is saying is undefined is in a component that is called from my vehicle.index template. This is why I'm so confused. When I transition to say Settings, Ember is trying to parse a component that isn't in the Settings template.

This is my environment info.

```
Ember 1.8.0-beta.1
Handlebars-runtime 1.2.1
jQuery 2.1.1
```

Here is the actual error and stack trace. You can see that the error occurs after the transition into settings.

```
Transitioned into 'settings' ember.js:15160
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'NotificationRead' of undefined ember.js:12138
```

Here is the call stack for the error

```
ChainNodePrototype.unchain ember.js:12138
ChainNodePrototype.remove ember.js:12114
unwatchPath ember.js:19438
unwatch ember.js:19508
removeObserver ember.js:16598
(anonymous function) ember.js:42755
apply ember.js:19278
sendEvent ember.js:14426
__exports__.default.Mixin.create.trigger ember.js:31415
apply ember.js:19280
superFunction ember.js:15752
EmberObject.extend.trigger ember.js:40418
apply ember.js:19280
superWrapper ember.js:18857
Renderer.willDestroyElement ember.js:38986
Renderer_beforeRemove ember.js:10757
Renderer_remove ember.js:10714
EmberObject.extend.destroy ember.js:40444
apply ember.js:19278
superWrapper ember.js:18857
apply ember.js:19278
superFunction ember.js:15752
CoreView.extend.destroy ember.js:42565
apply ember.js:19278
superWrapper ember.js:18857
(anonymous function) ember.js:40265
applyStr ember.js:19294
sendEvent ember.js:14420
notifyBeforeObservers ember.js:17429
propertyWillChange ember.js:17241
set ember.js:17715
trySet ember.js:17783
(anonymous function) ember.js:11601
tryable ember.js:14313
tryFinally ember.js:19059
suspendListener ember.js:14316
_suspendObserver ember.js:16628
Binding._sync ember.js:11600
DeferredActionQueues.invoke ember.js:674
DeferredActionQueues.flush ember.js:728
Backburner.end ember.js:134
Backburner.run ember.js:189
apply ember.js:19283
run ember.js:17857
__exports__.default.EmberObject.extend._bubbleEvent ember.js:38252
(anonymous function) ember.js:38203
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:4409
elemData.handle jquery.js:4095
```

**Update - 9/10/2014**
Sorry about the delay but I've been sick. Here is the code requested. This is the method in Ember that is throwing the error

```
ChainNodePrototype.unchain = function(key, path) {
  var chains = this._chains;
  var node = chains[key];

  // unchain rest of path first...
  if (path && path.length>1) {
    key  = firstKey(path);
    path = path.slice(key.length+1);
    node.unchain(key, path);
  }

  // delete node if needed.
  node.count--;
  if (node.count<=0) {
    delete chains[node._key];
    node.destroy();
  }

};
```

And here is the code for component template.

```
<header class="alertsModule__header">
    <svg class="shape-exclamation_point_warning" viewBox="0 0 65 65"><use xlink:href="#shape-exclamation_point_warning"></use></svg>
    <h1 class="alertsModule__title">{{total}} New Alerts</h1>
</header>
{{#each item in items}}
{{!-- When trying to just do the section and div tags in the #if statement the HTML broke. Not sure why --}}

{{#if item.NotificationRead}}
<section class="miniAlert--read">
    <div class="miniAlert--read__inner">
        <svg class="shape-{{unbound alertIcon item.NotificationType}}" viewBox="0 0 65 65"><use xlink:href="#shape-{{unbound alertIcon item.NotificationType}}"></use></svg>
        <span class="icon-arrow-right"></span>
        <h1 class="miniAlert--unread__title">{{item.NotificationName}}</h1>
        <span class="miniAlert--unread__timestamp">Today, 12:23PM</span>
    </div>
</section>
{{else}}
<section class="miniAlert--unread">
    <div class="miniAlert--unread__inner">
        <svg class="shape-{{unbound alertIcon item.NotificationType}}" viewBox="0 0 65 65"><use xlink:href="#shape-{{unbound alertIcon item.NotificationType}}"></use></svg>
        <span class="icon-arrow-right"></span>
        <h1 class="miniAlert--unread__title">{{item.NotificationName}}</h1>
        <span class="miniAlert--unread__timestamp">Today, 12:23PM</span>
    </div>
</section>
{{/if}}
{{/each}}
{{#link-to "alerts" class="seeAllBtn--alerts"}}
    <span class="seeAllBtn--alerts__inner">See all alert history</span>
    <span class="icon-arrow-right"></span>
{{/link-to}}
```

Comment: Could you try to name all nested resources in vehicle resource using full path (`this.resource('vehicle.alerts')`, `this.resource('vehicle.reminders.reminder')` and so on)?

Comment: No joy unfortunately.

Comment: Can you share the code that throws that error (i.e. by clicking the topmost link in your stack trace)?  I often find this helps when debugging Ember errors.

Comment: Can you also include the source code of the component you're including?  It's possible the component is hooking into the `willTransition` or `didTransition` events on the route, and trying to dispose of itself, or perhaps just the `NotificationRead` property.

Comment: I found that if components have ```on``` listeners in and is not switch to ```off``` in ```willClearRender``` i get strange error messages.